# How can I control the texturing of the pieces created by cell fracture?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, particles

I am trying to make a simple box explode to some extent. I have chosen to try out cell fracture and it works fine but how would I fix the inside of my object looking so weird? Is there a different approach required?

Here is object before explosion:
[image: box before explosion]

Box after explosion, the pieces look weird, I was hoping to see just wood textures on the inside, would this require me to redo the UV map after I applied the cell fracture?

[image: Exploded box]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "*the pieces look weird*", this is pretty subjective. What did you expect them to look like?

Comment: May this help (have a look at 13m40s and further)?
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUUi2AdLtmk

Comment: There's a tricky part in retrieving usable texture coordinates for fractured objects. A possible answer - but rather advanced - is on this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58932/apply-object-texture-coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed doubles which there was 512 and then did the cell fracturing with source limit of 6 and got desired results

[image: Broken image]